# Update customer password directly in database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer-attribute, password

If I have access to my database, can I manually override a customer password? This is my local development environment.

I have little knowledge of password encryption but I would like to be able to log out on a previously setup customer account and my forgot password link is not working.

As far as I can see this is stored in the **customer_entity_varchar** table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

Replace `testtest` with your new password and `$customer_entity_id` with the customers `entity_id` in the `customer_entity` table.

```
update customer_entity_varchar set value = md5('testtest') where entity_id=$customer_entity_id and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'password_hash' and entity_type_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access to database through phpmyadmin the follow this steps. **customer_entity** is the responsible table for this.

1. select the customer and click on edit.
2. Check for the password_hash column name.
3. Remove the total value which is already existing in text field next to it.
4. Now enter your new password(normal letters/special symbols/numerics)
5. Now before that there is a drop down. select MD5 from here.
6. Now click on GO button.

That's it. Your password has been modified.

NOTE: In magento2 the table is **customer_entity**, but I dont remember what it is for Magento1. But the process is same for both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is snippet if you have the customers e-mail address, just replace `$EMAIL` below with customers e-mail address and `$PASSWORD` with plain-text password.

```
UPDATE `customer_entity_varchar` 
    SET `value` = MD5("$PASSWORD") 
    WHERE `entity_id` IN (SELECT `entity_id` FROM `customer_entity` WHERE `email` = "$EMAIL") 
    AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = "password_hash" AND `entity_type_id` = 1) 
    LIMIT 1;
```